# Butcher/Cooking Twine - safe for BBQ?

Tags: roasting, barbecue

Is cooking twine safe for BBQ? I see twine safely used in the oven, but I need this on a charcoal rotisserie. I'm worried that the twine will burn off. Does anyone know if twine is safe? Or if there is an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used butchers twine on the grill many times with only the cut ends charring a bit.  As the meat cooks the twine absorbs some of the fluid that it exudes, which evaporates and cools the twine some.  By the time the twine chars the meat has started to shrink and usually the shape has at least started to set.

As an alternative you can use wire. Stainless steel wire for this purpose can be purchased online from many grilling and BBQ retailers. For larger projects, like whole hog rotisserie, I've seen people use chicken wire fencing material.  Just make sure to thoroughly clean off any oil or coating that may be on the wire before using it on food.

Answer (score 0):

The cooking environment on your grill will be no hotter than your oven. Most times it will be cooler, in fact. If your twine is in a position to combust, then it is too close to the fire.

Comment: Even if the twine doesn't actually catch fire, it could still char enough to no longer actually work as twine, couldn't it?